# Remove background image on last li

Tags: html, css, wordpress

HTML

```
<div>
<ul class="menubar">
 <li>home</li>
 <li>product</li>
 <li>about us</li>
 <li>contact us</li>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menubar li
{
    float: left;
    position: relative; 
    display: block;
    text-decoration: underline;
    text-transform:capitalize
    background:url(../image/rightborder.png) no-repeat right center;
}

.menubar li:hover
{   

    background: #FF0000 ; 
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

This work is working fine but the problem is with `background:url(../image/rightborder.png)` is coming after the last menu "Contact Us". Is there anyway to turn off that.

Comment: You need to close your ul tag firstly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this into the CSS and it may help

```
.menubar li:last-child { background:none}
```

But it doesn't work properly on below IE8

Comment: Please correct it. Write like this li:last-child instead of this li.last-child

Answer (score 2):

Add a `class` attribute to the last item, say `<li class=last>contact us</li>`, and add the rule `.menubar li.last { background-image: none; }`.

This works on all CSS-enabled browsers. Though somewhat clumsy, the use of a class selector is safest, and the clumsyness factor is rather irrelevant when it’s a matter of a single list.

Comment: How I can define a class on dynamic li? The whole menu is coming from a Wordpress Dynamic Plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this also:

```
.menubar li + li
{
    background:url(../image/rightborder.png) no-repeat left center;
}
```

First close your **UL**

Comment: who give me a down vote please explain me the reason so it's good for me :)

Comment: I gave you one upvote on each comment and answer. Its a good answer